# Laravel multi-auth different table for admin and user but one login page

Tags: laravel, roles, laravel-jetstream

Is it possible to have two different tables for users and admin but one login page? I already used middleware and Spatie permission, but I need them to separate because some info doesn't match if they are together in one table.

**For example:**
Admin needs name, employee number. At the same time, users need a name, address, student number, etc.

I need suggestions on how to do that to study it.

Comment: yes it is possible, anything is possible given the time to do it. i dont know what other answer you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you! just want to know because I have been searching but all I can see is single table multi-auth.

Comment: just override the login controller method and try to login the admin, if it fails, try to login the user. depend on which is successful, redirect to the proper page afterward. if it fails for both show the error.

Comment: having multiple user tables always turns out to be a bad idea in the long run.  Users are users, it does not matter their role. When it comes to authentication then they should be the same.  If you want to store different attributes then consider different profile tables that hold the right combination of fields for that type of user.  This can be done with a polymorphic relationship